How to parse json formatted file with no extension in Pentaho
I have a json formatted file at a url that doesnt include an extension e.g. https://whatever/path-to-json
When I parse with json input, all fields are null. If i save the file locally and add the json extension ... then run again, everything is correct.
WT..
